# How to make typescript compiler to print list of file names it is compiling?

Tags: typescript

`tsc --noEmit` will not emit outputs. Even If I use `tsc` without `--noEmit` option, it is printing anything. How to make compiler print list of filenames that it is compiling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no command printing names of TS files in compilation process.

This command will print every compiled JS file: `--listEmittedFiles`